# Error After the transfer of the application to a new server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rake assets:clean --trace


rake aborted!
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile.rb:239: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...rl(object, name, *args, prefix: Refile.mount_point, filename...
...                               ^
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile.rb:239: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
...: Refile.mount_point, filename: nil, format: nil, host: Refi...
...                               ^
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile.rb:239: Can't assign to nil
...ile.mount_point, filename: nil, format: nil, host: Refile.ho...
...                               ^
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile.rb:239: Can't assign to nil
...nt, filename: nil, format: nil, host: Refile.host)
...                               ^
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile.rb:239: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile.rb:317: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/refile-d1311a0d98f8/lib/refile/rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
/var/www/test/releases/20160120185703/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/www/test/releases/20160120185703/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: was the old server using the same version of Ruby?

Comment: old server uses version 1.9.1 of Ruby and Rails 4.1.4 and new server uses 1.9.3 of Ruby and 4.1.4 of Rails

Comment: user rvm to create a gemset for the project and install gems in that. This should help in any conflicts arising due to version mismatch

Comment: Can you Explain that step by step? A'm a newbie in ruby. Thanks!

Comment: i have installed ruby 1.9.1 then executed rake command again as follows:                                                                              `code` user@ubuntu:/var/www/test/current$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.1-p431 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

user@ubuntu:/var/www/test/current$ rake assets:clean

    Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.0.

    You're running
      ruby 1.9.1p431 (2011-02-18 revision 30908) [x86_64-linux]

    Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue. `code`